# What to do if a user posts multiple related and poor quality posts?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

Today I've noticed a single user post 3 questions with titles starting with `Main Support Item Build` followed by a number (denoting which one of his posts it was). In each case, the question was a line or two asking about usage of an item in League of Legends. I noticed that every single question that was asked needed to be edited by another user to have a descriptive and working title and reword the question to make sense.

I had edited one of them but by the time I saw the third one, I did not feel like it is acceptable to put it upon other people to ensure that this user's posts are nice and clean, so I flagged it for moderator attention and explained my action.

For the future, what should be done in cases like this?

The questions referenced are below:

[The first one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284240/main-support-item-builds)

[The second -- look at revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284305/what-should-i-do-with-my-sightstone-as-a-support)

[The third](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284332/main-support-item-builds-3-6-17)

[another -- see revision history](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284325/what-is-face-of-the-mountains-best-strategic-use)

Comment: Downvotes are your very best friend. Enough of them ensure askers like that get question banned, and can't bother us anymore.

Comment: Yes but the question that was edited became popular, which would allow users like this to continue this behavior... It just feels wrong to expect other users to salvage all of your posts for you and then get rewarded for it.

Comment: Then everybody wins. We get a good quality question that can help future readers, and the asker gets an answer. It feels wrong to reward low effort contributions, but remember, its not about the user; its about the content.

Comment: @Frank that's true. I think that it might be beneficial to temp ban users who post too many down voted posts in a short time period or something, though. Is that already a thing?

Comment: That's what downvotes do. Give the system enough signal, and it knows when to block users from asking. Best part is, its automatic. And unless the user shapes up, permanent, too.

Comment: Ah okay, that is really good, then. I didn't know that. I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: [His newest question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/284353/which-champions-work-best-with-zekes-harbinger) follows in suit with the rest as well. On one hand, cutting the gem out of the stone isn't that hard. On the other, there's an onus on the user to do some of the work first when sending that stone in.

Comment: @NBN-Alex yeah, I don't have an issue cleaning up a post or two, but when I notice that I'm cleaning up very similar posts in the same day by the same user, it feels like babysitting instead of helping.

Comment: @Vemonus -  Some users barely even realise that their posts are causing headaches, at that point it may be helpful to (constructively!) address the user directly in a comment. Something like *"Hi, you may have noticed that I have had to edit a few of your posts today so that they're more coherent & easier to understand. In future, please try to make sure that your question title reflects the problem you're facing and that the question body is free of grammatical errors & spelling mistakes. If you improve these areas tou'll find that you get a better reception with your posts in future."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Frank said is correct: If a user posts low quality content then downvote it, and then let the system take care of the rest. If a users balance between low-quality and high-quality posts becomes too imbalanced towards mostly low quality content they'll eventually have posting restrictions enforced on them until their already existing posts are improved and upvoted.